# R3F OrbitControls with fixed camera position

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I'm using this for a 360 image and I need the camera to stay fixed at (0,0,0)

If I update the camera position the controls stop working.

I've seen this post https://codeworkshop.dev/blog/2020-04-03-adding-orbit-controls-to-react-three-fiber/ which kind of has a fix but seems out of date, the extend functionality doesn't make orbitControls available.

I've tried various combinations of

```
  const onChange = () => {
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    ref.current.update();
  };
```

Or

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && scene.projection === SceneProjection['3603D']) {
      camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      ref.current.update();
    }
  }, [ref, scene]);
```

Is there a simple way to lock the camera position with OrbitControls and just rotate the camera?

Comment: I think you might be able to set .maxDistance to 0. That way it only rotates around its origin.
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxDistance

Comment: Great answer thanks. Setting it to 0 breaks the OrbitControls but setting to 0.1 works great. Thank you!

Comment: @Marquizzo if you make that an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to set `controls.maxDistance` to something really small, like 0.01. That way it only rotates around its origin by an imperceptible amount.

You can read more about the `.maxDistance` attribute in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.maxDistance)